# `*arg0` does not live long enough - wasm_bindgen

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

When running the following code:

**Cargo.toml**

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
wasm-bindgen = {version = "0.2.67", features = ["serde-serialize"] }
wasm-bindgen-futures = "0.4.17"
```

**lib.rs**

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Output {
    strings: Vec<String>,
}

#[wasm_bindgen] //error occuring here
pub async fn return_strings(_input: &str) -> JsValue {
    
    //example function that returns a js value
    let strings: Vec<String> = Default::default();
    let output = Output { strings };
    
    JsValue::from_serde(&output).unwrap()
}
```

I get the following error:

`*arg0` does not live long enough
borrowed value does not live long enoughargument requires that `*arg0` is borrowed for `'static`


If anyone could let me know why, I would be a huge help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is caused when Rust assumes that the future returned by `return_strings` has the same lifetime as `_input` even though it doesn't actually borrow from it. Basically, the de-sugared function signature looks like:

```rust
pub fn return_strings<'a>(_input: &'a str) -> impl Future<Output = JsValue> + 'a;
```

The generated code wants a future with `'static` lifetime, but the returned future actually winds up with the lifetime of a temporary string variable.

[The developers are aware of this limitation](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/2195). Probably the easiest solution is to take an owned `String` or `Box<str>` argument instead of a borrowed `&str`.